# How to solve the issue summary function conflicting with tikz in R Mark down?

Tags: latex, r-markdown, pdflatex

I customized my rmarkdown document with logo on every page, YAML header `output: pdf_document: includes: in_header: header.tex` command. When I included `summary(cars)` command, error returned:

> ! Package tikz Error: Sorry, some package has redefined the meaning of the math
>   -mode dollar sign. This is incompatible with tikz and its calc library and migh
>   t cause unrecoverable errors.

I have no problem generating a summary table with knitr::kable, `kable(summary(cars))` worked fine with my customized format.
My header.tex:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{angle=0, 
               scale=.45,
               position=current page.north east,
               contents={
                         \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
                           \node [anchor=north east, inner sep=20pt]  at (current page.north east)
                             {\includegraphics{logo.png}}; 
                         \end{tikzpicture}
                          }
              }
```

Any help leading to solution or inspiration of solution is much appreciated.
Add Session Info:

```
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] stargazer_5.2.1      xtable_1.8-2         kableExtra_0.7.0     
gridExtra_2.3        RGA_0.4.2           
 [6] googleAuthR_0.6.2    httr_1.3.1           AnomalyDetection_1.0 knitr_1.20           RColorBrewer_1.1-2  
[11] tmaptools_1.2-3      tmap_1.11-1          countrycode_1.00.0   forcats_0.3.0        stringr_1.3.0       
[16] dplyr_0.7.4          purrr_0.2.4          readr_1.1.1          tidyr_0.8.0          tibble_1.4.2        
[21] ggplot2_2.2.1        tidyverse_1.2.1     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] colorspace_1.3-2   deldir_0.1-14      class_7.3-14       gdalUtils_2.0.1.7  leaflet_1.1.0     
[6] rgdal_1.2-18       rprojroot_1.3-2    satellite_1.0.1    base64enc_0.1-3    dichromat_2.0-0   
[11] rstudioapi_0.7     lubridate_1.7.2    xml2_1.2.0         codetools_0.2-15   splines_3.4.4     
[16] R.methodsS3_1.7.1  mnormt_1.5-5       geojsonlint_0.2.0  jsonlite_1.5       broom_0.4.3       
[21] png_0.1-7          R.oo_1.21.0        rgeos_0.3-26       shiny_1.0.5        compiler_3.4.4    
[26] backports_1.1.2    mapview_2.3.0      assertthat_0.2.0   Matrix_1.2-12      lazyeval_0.2.1    
[31] cli_1.0.0          htmltools_0.3.6    tools_3.4.4        bindrcpp_0.2       coda_0.19-1       
[36] gtable_0.2.0       glue_1.2.0         reshape2_1.4.3     gmodels_2.16.2     V8_1.5            
[41] Rcpp_0.12.16       sunburstR_2.0.0    cellranger_1.1.0   raster_2.6-7       spdep_0.7-4       
[46] gdata_2.18.0       nlme_3.1-131.1     udunits2_0.13      iterators_1.0.9    crosstalk_1.0.0   
[51] psych_1.7.8        rvest_0.3.2        mime_0.5           gtools_3.5.0       devtools_1.13.5   
[56] XML_3.98-1.10      LearnBayes_2.15.1  MASS_7.3-49        scales_0.5.0       hms_0.4.2         
[61] parallel_3.4.4     expm_0.999-2       yaml_2.1.18        curl_3.1           memoise_1.1.0     
[66] geosphere_1.5-7    stringi_1.1.7      jsonvalidate_1.0.0 highr_0.6          foreach_1.4.4     
[71] e1071_1.6-8        boot_1.3-20        spData_0.2.8.1     rlang_0.2.0        pkgconfig_2.0.1   
[76] bitops_1.0-6       evaluate_0.10.1    lattice_0.20-35    sf_0.6-0           bindr_0.1.1       
[81] labeling_0.3       htmlwidgets_1.0    osmar_1.1-7        plyr_1.8.4         magrittr_1.5      
[86] R6_2.2.2           DBI_0.8            pillar_1.2.1       haven_1.1.1        foreign_0.8-69    
[91] withr_2.1.2        units_0.5-1        RCurl_1.95-4.10    sp_1.2-7           modelr_0.1.1      
[96] crayon_1.3.4       rmapshaper_0.3.0   utf8_1.1.3         KernSmooth_2.23-15 rmarkdown_1.9     
[101] grid_3.4.4         readxl_1.0.0       webshot_0.5.0      digest_0.6.15      classInt_0.1-24   
[106] httpuv_1.3.6.2     R.utils_2.6.0      openssl_1.0.1      stats4_3.4.4       munsell_0.4.3     
[111] viridisLite_0.3.0
```

And YAML Header:

```
title: Title
author: "XXX"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%x')`"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: yes
    latex_engine: pdflatex
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex
  word_document: default
geometry: margin = 1in
fontsize: 11pt
```

P.S., when I used `header-includes` command and customized document layout with latex package `fancyhdr`, everything worked well and compiled to pdf successfully.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the error with the information you provided and my own `logo.png`.

Comment: Thanks @Martin Schmelzer, I added session info and header info. Is there any other essential info needed for debugging?